# Click and Drag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an element respond when the user clicks **and** drags the mouse.

I need the response to happen every `mousemove` while the single `mousedown` event is happening.

I'm using jQuery, but I'm open to a pure JS implementation as well. Here is what I've tried:

```
$('.element').on('mousedown', function (e) {
  $('.element').on('mousemove', function (e) {
    console.log("response");
  });
  $('.element').off('mousedown');
});
```

This works, but it will work after I clicked once, even if I don't keep doing the `mousedown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook into the `mouseup` event and unbind the `mousemove` there:

```
$('.element').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    $('.element').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        console.log("response");
    });
}).on("mouseup", function(e) {
    $('.element').off('mousemove');
});
```